# Find the number of generators of a cyclic group with a given order n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let us say that $n = 5$. The number of generators of a finite cyclic group would be the number of numbers that are *relatively prime* to $n$ and the identity element.

Here, when $n=5$, the number of generators would be $2,3,5$. We would also have to include the identity element generator, $e$ for each finite cyclic group. Thus the number of generators of a cyclic group with order $5$ would be 4.

Similarly, when $n=12$, the number of relatively prime generators would be $2,3,5,7,11$ and $1$ for a total of 6.

- I think I understand how to find the number of generators of a cyclic finite group, but I can't really explain why.
- I also can't draw the connection to this statement:

  > The order of an element in a finite cyclic group is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n=e$, denoted ord $a$.
- How would I **prove that the order of an element $a \in G$ equals the order of $G$?** What am I failing to consider?

Comment: Do you mean, if $G=\langle a \rangle$, then  to prove $|a|=|G|$ ?

Comment: You are confusing a number of different things and you might need to improve your notation to make yourself clear. The identity element in a group is only a generator of the whole group if the group itself has order $1$ - ie it is the trivial group. You need to tell us what the numbers $2,3,5$ mean - you say these are "the number of generators" - that doesn't make much sense as you've written it - are these elements of the group, or something else?

Comment: @MarkBennet The question says "Find the number of generators of a cyclic group having the given order 8". I would answer with "The number of generators of a cyclic group with order 8 is 4". I am sorry I can't explain much further, that is why I originally posted, to try to get better organized thoughts and lay out my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

A cyclic group of order $n$ has $\phi(n)$ different generators, see these duplicates:

[Cyclic Group Generators of Order $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155137/cyclic-group-generators-of-order-n)

[How many generator has a cyclic group of order n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336784/how-many-generator-has-a-cyclic-group-of-order-n)

[How to find a generator of a cyclic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group)